# Flutter: Position Icon after TextField with same height

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, responsive, flutter-web

I'm trying to achieve the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKabx.png

I basically tried everything, I have both TextField and Icon in a Row but I can't seem to give them the same height without doing it hard coded and non responsive.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: TextField(
                      maxLines: 1,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Search Employee',
                        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 0)),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add_box,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone asking, after a lot of investigating this is how I solved it:

- TextField have a default height of 48px which doesn't change on any screen or resolution.
- So you just have to match the size of the Icon to the TextField once(Yes, this can and should be hardcoded, I used a little bit more than 48 on the size cuz my icon had a build in padding which can't be remove) and it's all done.

Comment: Very odd how it's hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

There is temporary solution of this because icon is by default center of any widget

```
  return Card(
    elevation: 5,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    ),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: 1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                hintText: 'Search Employee',
                hintStyle:
                Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black, width: 0)),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 3,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

i just use Icons.add in Container and give container a black color

Answer (score 0):

[image]
**You Can try this Code**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 1,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Search Employee',
                      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 0)),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.010,),
                FittedBox(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add_box,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```